# how to select documents with in range using $gt and $lt in springdata mongodb?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Error:
  Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'stop_number' expression specified as 'stop_number : { "$lt" : "5358e8d55d911a8b8d9ed4401"}'. Criteria already contains 'stop_number : { "$gt" : 1}'.

and my java program is

query4.addCriteria(Criteria.where("stop_number").gt(current_stop_number).and("stop_number").lt(stop_id+1).and("bus_id").is(bus_id));

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I propose to you.

1) You should create a list of Criterias:

```
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
criterias.add(Criteria.where("stop_number").gt(current_stop_number));
criterias.add(Criteria.where("stop_number").lt(stop_id+1));
```

2) So, you can create a Criteria from a list of criterias in such a way to unite your criterias by "$and" operator :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]));
```

3) Last thing, to get a query:

```
Query query = new Query(criteria);
```

4) Execute with a mongoTemplate

```
List<ClassName> documents = mongoTemplate.find(query, ClassName.class);
```